# How to make a new page to open in the same tab. Form POST method. Flask

Tags: python, html, forms, post, flask

I have the following problem when I try to open the concrete page with form, when I press form button, the new instance of the page opens in the new tab. But I want it to open in the same tab. How can I do it?

The interested fact is that when I go to the new tab and press the same button in the same form, a new page opens in the same tab.

I have the following Flask code:

```py
@app.route('/wifi', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def wifi():
    result_dict = None
    pic_end = ""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        start_date = request.form['calendar1']
        end_date = request.form["calendar2"]
        period = request.form["period"]
        # do some work here ...

    return render_template("test_wifi.html", result_dict=result_dict, wifipic="wifi" + pic_end)
```

I have the following html page:

```html
<form action="" class="ordinary_form" id="wifi_form">

    <label for="calendar1"> Choose period start: </label>
    <input type="date" name="calendar1" id="calendar1" required> <br> <br>
    <label for="calendar2"> Choose period end: </label>
    <input type="date" name="calendar2" id="calendar2" required></p>
    <label for="period"> Step size: </label>
    <select required name="period" id="period">
        <option value="0">Day</option>
        <option value="1">Week</option>
        <option value="2">Month</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>


    <input target="_self" type="submit" value="SEND" formtarget="{{url_for('wifi')}}" formmethod="post" onclick="loading();">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is as follows:

I shoudl have made changes in the form line:

```
<form action="" method="POST"  class="ordinary_form" id="wifi_form">
```

and in input submit part:

```
<input type="submit" value="SEND" onclick="loading();">
```